# how to tackle with textblock in wp8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

here is the code of my text block,

i want to show the difference of two numbers in it,

but it gives error, whien i run the app.

```
Error: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

here is the code,

```
        TextBlock diffBlock = new TextBlock();


        diffBlock.FontSize = 30;

        diffBlock.Text = " ";

        diffBlock.Text = (total - double.Parse(income.Inc)).ToString();

        ContentPanel.Children.Add(diffBlock);

        Difference.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        Difference.Text = "Remaining Budget: " + diffBlock;
```

how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use textbolck as a string use Text property. this will resolve your problem.

```
TextBlock diffBlock = new TextBlock();


        diffBlock.FontSize = 30;

        diffBlock.Text = " ";
      if(income!=null)
        diffBlock.Text = (total - double.Parse(income.Inc)).ToString();
       else
         diffBlock.Text = total.ToString();
         ContentPanel.Children.Add(diffBlock);

        Difference.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        Difference.Text = "Remaining Budget: " + diffBlock.Text;
```

Comment: what type of total and income in you code .....diffBlock.Text = (total - double.Parse(income.Inc)).ToString(); Here. If i guess right your income is null.

Comment: yes, u're rite, that is null, and here's the code for that.

    query = "SELECT * FROM UInc";

                List<UInc> incomeList = db.Query<UInc>(query);
                UInc income = null;
                if (incomeList.Count > 0)
                {
                    income = incomeList[0];

                    Inc.Text = "Monthly Income: " + income.Inc;
                }

Comment: @Qaiser Please check my ans i made edits that avoid you error. but also check why your income is getting a null, check with your db query.

Comment: jai, income is getting null, because it's from user input, after running the app. user will input the income..

Comment: @Qaiser so income is a textBox ?? but it look like an object type.

Comment: thanks @Jai it's resolved now, by putting if conditing for null income.